# Magento admin login redirect to frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, login, admin-login

When I try to login in magento admin and when I enter correct login detail I get redirected to the frontend.

I am using xampp

```
http://localhost/venkys/admin/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/e2c5440e3f8d569e3de19229617cba58/
```

This is the url in address bar.

And I am getting 404 page.

But when I try to change address bar to

```
http://localhost/venkys/admin/dashboard/index/key/e2c5440e3f8d569e3de19229617cba58/
```

Its working totally fine

Any help

Comment: issue is on localhost or on server

Comment: On localhost @AshishMadankar

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a result of improper routing.

There are 2 ways this can happen;

**1.**
Through your htaccess file (for example when you try to remove the index.php from the URL). Make sure your htaccess contains the following and not something else:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

**2.**
The url values you put in under

```
    web/secure/base_url       
    web/unsecure/base_url
```

In your core_config_data database table are incorrect. They should be http://domain.com and https://domain.com respectively.

Answer (score 1):

First you can check your settings in httpd.conf this line :
AllowOverride All

Should be ALL not None