# Magento 2.3.4: Admin user login redirects to frontend 404 with key in URL

Tags: magento2, admin, admin-user

When I try to login from the magento admin it redirects me to the frontend with '/key/6732689239' in the URL.

Comment: Hope this link will help you. link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114670/magento-admin-login-redirect-to-frontend

Comment: It is on server not on localhost. @MPRaj